# Small pie-chart without any numbers or text

Tags: pgf-pie

Does anyone know how to draw a small pie-chart without labels?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pie[ 
 color = {black!10, black!40},radius = 0.5] {37.5, 62.5}    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `/tikz/nodes={text opacity=0,overlay}` as option for`\pie`.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pie[ 
  color = {black!10, black!40},radius = .5,
  /tikz/nodes={text opacity=0,overlay}% <- 
] {37.5, 62.5}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thats a pretty simple way! Thx!

Answer (score 3):

You can find an example using Tikz [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/pie-chart/). You can remove the labels by removing the corresponding lines. You obtain the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\slice}[4]{
  \pgfmathparse{0.5*#1+0.5*#2}
  \let\midangle\pgfmathresult
  \draw[thick,fill=black!10] (0,0) -- (#1:1) arc (#1:#2:1) -- cycle;
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]

\newcounter{a}
\newcounter{b}
\foreach \p/\t in {20/type A, 4/type B, 11/type C, 49/type D, 16/other}
{
  \setcounter{a}{\value{b}}
  \addtocounter{b}{\p}
  \slice{\thea/100*360}
      {\theb/100*360}
      {\p\%}{\t}
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```