# pgf-pie: not show numbers

Tags: pgf-pie

I have the code:

```
\documentclass{article}                                                                                                                                                                                     
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                                                                                                                                                                                 
\usepackage{pgf-pie}                                                                                                                                                                                        
\begin{document}                                                                                                                                                                                            
\begin{tikzpicture}                                                                                                                                                                                         
  \pie[text=,before number=, after number=,color={blue!33.33, blue!33.33, white!33.33}]                                                                                                                      
      {33.33, 33.33, 33.33}                                                                                                                                                                                 
\end{tikzpicture}                                                                                                                                                                                           
\end{document}
```

which produces the output

[image]

How can I hide the numbers (33.33)?

Comment: At least according to the documentation this is no valid use-case. You should make a feature-request (contact author).

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329030/ https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304142/

Comment: Perhaps you could just draw the wedges yourself without using `pgf-pie`?  Something like: `\filldraw[fill=blue!20!white, draw=black] (0,0) -- (  0:4cm) arc (  0:120:4cm) -- (0,0);`

Comment: Using `before number=\pgfsetfillopacity{0.0}` is a solution for hiding the numbers only, leaving the labels visible.